# IllegalStateException when service is started when app is in foreground on Oreo

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo

**Given:** I have a service which I start in `onStart()` of an activity and I stop the service in `onStop()` of the same activity.

**Known:** According to the Android docs in Android 8 there are background restrictions imposed wherein a service cannot be started when the app is in background and will throw an `IllegalStateException`. (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

**Inference:** But this restriction does not affect my scenario since my service runs only when the app is in foreground(between `onStart()` and `onStop()`).

**Problem:** Yet I see one crash in google console throwing an `IllegalStateException` on an Android 8(Oreo) device for the line `startService()`. Any idea why this exception is thrown when the service is started when app is in foreground? Can there be other scenarios when an `IllegalStateException` is thrown for `startService()`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      startforegroundservice(your_service);
}else{
      startservice(your_service);
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use a foreground service since it will keep showing a notification as long as it runs. I can use JobIntentService instead. But the question is why can't I use a simple Service when I intend to run it only when the app is in foreground.

Comment: @DevAndroid for android 8 you cannot use only startservice because its behaviour  change in andorid 8. Either you have to startforeground or jobIntentService or jonScheduler

Comment: The Android documention says `While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely`. (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)  I am creating the service in `onStart()` of the Activity and hence it is allowed.